# aspnet core and AzureAD: is there a way to intercept the authentication?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

When creating an ASP.NET Core MVC 2.1 project, I can set the authentication method to Azure AD. Now, the generated code does work and I've noticed that the authentication is set up like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
```

Now, when if I setup the OpenIdConnect provider directly, I can set up the Events property which would let me hook up code during the authentication process:

```
services.AddOpenIdConnect(options => {
         options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents {
                   OnTokenValidated = PerformExtraValidationsBeforeLoggingIn,
         }
});
```

Is there a way to do the same with the Azure Ad helpers that are used by the Wizard or must I go use the openid connect directly in order to achieve this?

Thanks,
Luis

Comment: Set up through the AD Connect wizard you mean? Even with the AD Authentication using ADConnect you still need to hook up the code and store tokens through an ADAL library like OpenID Connect. If I understand what you are asking then yes, you will need to use OpenID Connect directly.

Comment: Hello. I've ended up using OpenIdConnect directly because I didn't find a way  to handle the openidconnect's token validated event...